# Is it ok to edit a older question, to bring it to the homepage, if our query is similar?

Tags: discussion

Let's say I'm trying to implement something, and need help; and I come here (the main site) to ask a question. And while posting the query, I come across a similar question; but find that none of the users have answered it or answers are not to the point.

So, I have an option to *Start a bounty* for that question. As a second option can I go ahead and just edit the question in order to bring it to front page to draw attention? Off course, I'm aware that the edit should not be such that it changes the meaning of the original question. By *edit* I mean, can I elaborate the question to suite my requirement (pretty similar to the question and without changing the meaning).

Comment: I don't know of (and can't find) an official policy but I would suspect the best thing to do is place bounty, which is specifically intended for drawing attention to a question that you need more information on. I think by editing the question, however careful you are, you're going to dilute the original intent even if you don't change it completely. Perhaps you could link to the question and propose what changes you'd like to make and it can be discussed on a more specific basis?

Comment: @Clive - Sorry, I don't remember the question as of now, but I'm pretty sure I've come across this situation sometime around the end of last month. I did not ask a question, rather I used the point of view of the OP of the similar question and searched to find the solution and did find one :-) But that took some time.

Comment: And I agree that placing a bounty would be appropriate, but I've noticed that the the community user takes some (random maybe?) time to bounce the question back. So, by doing a edit I think is like _giving another try_.

Comment: I believe this is the canonical question on MSO about the topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the question if you make the question clearer, or add more details.

I think it is fine if you edit the question just to bump it once, or once in a while. Keep in mind that questions are automatically made a Community Wiki, when they are edited 10 times from their authors, or when they are edited from 5 different users; that is done to avoid users keep bumping questions to the front page.

Consider also that Community user bumps to the front page those questions that don't have an up-voted answer, where *up-voted* also includes accepted answers. (For the system, accepting an answer is another form of vote.)

Comment: This is pretty close to what I was thinking. Thank you for making it clearer.

Comment: I have updated my answer: You can edit a post 10 times, before it is changed to CW. You should not use those 10 edits just to bump the question to the front page, though. If a user keep editing a post in short time, moderators could temporary lock the post.

Comment: I must say that StackExchange network of sites is very well designed to pretty much handle everything. Learning a new feature everyday is fun :-) Way to go...